# linux bash find if not execute

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, event-handling

I need to create a bash script to run another script command if none of the files in the directory have been created within 30 mins.

I am not sure of the code I need but it needs to find and execute  if not matched. -

**find /folder/to/watch/* if-not 30 mins -exec fixscript.sh** or something?

When the script is ran I want it to check the files in the folder , if a file has not been created within the last 30 mins then to run the fixscript.sh

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be combined to a single find statement. The following would work, with the caveat that if a file is modified, it would be detected as "newer than 30 minutes".

```
if [ `find /folder/to/watch -mmin -30 | wc -l` -eq 0 ]; then
    /path/to/fixscript.sh
fi
```

Linux/Unix does not have an independent file creation attribute. Some filesystems might have it, though, but it can't be accessed from shell without c code and call to stat(). This uses "file modified" timestamp, which gets changed on not only file creation but also file edit.

Hannu

Comment: `find /folder/to/watch -mmin -30 | grep -q '.*' || fixscript.sh` would be more efficient. There's no need to see *how much* output `find` produces; we just need to determine if it produces anything or not.

Comment: `if [[ -z "$(find ... -print -quit)" ]]; then fixscript.sh; fi` would also be OK; limiting the output of `find` to a single string makes it feasible to just capture that and check if its output is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you don't have metadata for creation time, but only for last modification time, last file status change and last access time.

You can do:

```
if test ! [`find "your_file" -mmin +30`]
then
    `path/to/your/script.sh`
fi
```

the `-mmin` option is giving you last modification time.